# paginate_by how to display ellipsis - Django

Tags: html, django-views, ellipsis, pagination

I have a web built in Django, I would like to paginate like this(/admin)
[image]
But my page is paginated as below:
[image]
I have a list.html as below:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
      {% if page_obj.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

and in view.py:

```
ProjectListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 20
```